# -I flag JAVA command @ .bat CMAKE

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmake

I have to extract and generate some .h files from a jar and idl file.

Need to use a .bat from external developers:

```
    @echo off
    java -jar C:\WorkspaceSwim\trunk\iB\build\BlueGen\target\bluegen.jar -o                 C:\WorkspaceSwim\trunk\Example\Distribution\build\GeneratedDDSFiles         C:\WorkspaceSwim\trunk\Example\Distribution\Flight.idl
    set NDDSHOME=C:\WorkspaceSwim\trunk\iB\build\ToolBox\NDDS 
    set RPCDDSHOME=C:\WorkspaceSwim\trunk\iB\build\ToolBox\RPCDDS 
    setlocal
    set dir=%~dp0
    set args=%1
    :getarg
    shift
    if "%~1"=="" goto continue
    set args=%args% %1
    goto getarg
    :continue
    set JREHOME=%JAVA_HOME%
    "%JREHOME%\bin\java" -DPATH="%PATH%" -DNDDSHOME="%NDDSHOME%" -DRPCDDSHOME="%RPCDDSHOME%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%RPCDDSHOME%\classes\" com.eprosima.rpcdds.idl.RPCDDSGEN %args% "-I%RPCDDSHOME% /idl"
```

I think there are some fail on the script , but i can't see it. Maybe a problem with quotes? i tryied this 3 posibilities :

```
"%JREHOME%\bin\java" -DPATH="%PATH%" -DNDDSHOME="%NDDSHOME%" -DRPCDDSHOME="%RPCDDSHOME%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%RPCDDSHOME%\classes\" com.eprosima.rpcdds.idl.RPCDDSGEN %args% "-I%RPCDDSHOME%\idl"
```

**Error: principal class \idl doesn't found or load**

```
"%JREHOME%\bin\java" -DPATH="%PATH%" -DNDDSHOME="%NDDSHOME%" -DRPCDDSHOME="%RPCDDSHOME%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%RPCDDSHOME%\classes" com.eprosima.rpcdds.idl.RPCDDSGEN %args% "-I%RPCDDSHOME%\idl"
```

**Error: principal class com.eprosima.rpcdds.idl.RPCDDSGEN doesn't found or load**

```
"%JREHOME%\bin\java" -DPATH="%PATH%" -DNDDSHOME="%NDDSHOME%" -DRPCDDSHOME="%RPCDDSHOME%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%RPCDDSHOME%\classes\  com.eprosima.rpcdds.idl.RPCDDSGEN %args%" -I "%RPCDDSHOME%\idl"
```

**Unrecognized option: -I
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.**

Previusly i use this .cmake to generate the code that will run this .bat

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${DDSGeneratedFiles}
    COMMAND java -jar ${iB_BlueGen} -o ${GeneratedDDSDirName} ${LocatedFile} 
    COMMAND "set NDDSHOME=${iMASBlue_NDDS_DIR} &" "set RPCDDSHOME=${iB_RPCDDS_DIR} &"    ${RPCDDSGenerator} -replace -d ${GeneratedDDSDirName} -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${LocatedFile}
    DEPENDS ${IncludeDependencies} 
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${LocatedFile}
    COMMENT "Calling RPCDDS Generator '${RPCDDSGenerator}' on '${IdlFile}'"
    )
```

Thnx for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

To debug batch files, change line

```
 @echo off
```

in your batch file to

```
 @echo on
```

and run again